# Overwrite value using RowSelected

Tags: c#, acumatica

I was trying to custom the Purchase Receipt page (PO302000). What I was trying to do is to overwrite the Receipt Qty. field. So, I use RowSelected event which look like this

```
protected void POReceiptLine_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{

  var row = (POReceiptLine)e.Row;

  POInspectionDetail inspectLine = (POInspectionDetail)PXSelectorAttribute.Select<POReceiptLineExt.inspectionLine>(cache, row);
  POReceiptLineExt receiptLine = cache.GetExtension<POReceiptLineExt>(row);

  if(receiptLine.InspectionLine != null)
    {
      row.ReceiptQty = inspectLine.Acc;
    }
}
```

It works, but my problem is, the Open Qty. field which is the result of Ordered Qty. - Receipt Qty. become 0, which is shown in this picture:

[image: Using RowSelected event]

where it should be 180, based on this example.

And the value, which in this example is 20, is taken from another form that I create, and it looks like this:

[image: Inspection form]

Comment: Rowselected event is not a good option to do this. are you trying to load the receipt quantiity when the user create the PO receipt from PO?

Comment: Yes, but I added one more process, after PO, they need to do the inspection first, then go to receipt. And what I was trying to do is to load from inspection form

Comment: but users creating the receipt from PO screen using acumatica function?

Comment: yes, they use standard PO screen

Comment: "It works, but my problem is, the Open Qty. field which is the result of Ordered Qty." AS you said this, could you try using the setvalueext<> instead of just assigning the value?

Comment: It works, I use setvalueext<>. Thank you so much

Comment: you may accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It works, but my problem is, the Open Qty. field which is the result of Ordered Qty."

As you said this, could you try using the

> SetValueExt<>

instead of just assigning the value?